# access a third-party Android app's data using Dropbox HTTP API

Tags: dropbox-api

I'm a user of an Android app that is storing its data in my personal Dropbox account, presumably using the Dropbox API. How can I use the Dropbox API over HTTP to read the data that's associated with my account?

Answer (score 0):

If the app is storing files, you can just browse to them on any computer running the Dropbox desktop app, or you can browse to them on dropbox.com. You can also use [the API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers).

If it was using the deprecated Datastore API, you can find a "download datastores" link next to the app on your [account security page](https://www.dropbox.com/account/security). Unfortunately, because the API was deprecated last year and now fully turned off, there's no longer any API access to datastores.